# Android: How to get facebook profile picture into my dialog

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on a dialog box. When I click a button it should open  a dialog box  with a Facebook profile image. How can I achieve this? Below is my dialog box.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdailog);



                        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.fb);

                        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.fbshare);

                        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        });
                        dialog.show();
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: did you implemented some methods that will be downloading images or are you using some external library ?

Comment: no iam not downloadig any images if i loggin in fb on my device it should take that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at official [Android Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) at github

Also user profile picture is public, this means that authorization isn't requared and you can just load user page URL, parse the body of the response and get the image

Comment: there is no need to parse the whole page to get a user profile picture. Here is the URL for that: https://graph.facebook.com/<YOUR_USER_FACEBOOK_ID>/picture

Comment: Is it possible to use Graph API without authorization?

Comment: some parts of the api don't require access-tokens etc. and they are public so, yes it is. Have a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
URL url = new URL("https://www.graph.facebook.com/jesselchen/picture");
Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
image.setImageBitmap(pic);
```

Comment: in the above code we are directly mentioning the url of a particular person what if there is other user how to pass the url of other users?

Answer (score 1):

The graphAPI doesn't require authorisation for grabbing public data such as profile pictures.

Construct a URL like so:

```
String userID = "TheNameOrIDOfTheUserYouWant";
String urlConstruct = "https://www.graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture";
URL url = new URL(urlConstruct);
```

Then Just grab the data and load the image into an ImageView.

```
ImageView profilePic = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
Bitmap imageFromURL = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
profilePic.setImageBitmap(imageFromURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
URL url = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+fb_user_id+"/picture?type=large");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);  
Bitmap fbpicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
image.setImageBitmap(fbpicture);
```